# Почему операции над Path реализованы через статические методы?

Tags: java, файлы

ИМХО, `path.delete()` выглядит лучше, чем `Files.delete(path)`.

Но разработчики пакета `java.nio.file` предпочли реализовать операции с `Path` через статические методы класса `Files`. Почему?

Т. е. интерфейс `Path` можно было бы заменить на абстрактный класс с методами `delete()`, `isDirectory()` и пр., точно так же получив удобный механизм для реализации платформозависимых сущностей.

Comment: какой смысл в объекте path после вызова у него delete()? путь/линк/файл удален и сам объект представляет собой что?  
* [PHP:unlink](http://www.php.net/manual/ru/function.unlink.php)
* [Delphi:RemoveDir](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/VCL/2010/en/SysUtils.RemoveDir)
* [C++:boost::filesystem::remove_all](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_48_0/libs/filesystem/v3/doc/reference.html#remove_all)

и т.д.

Comment: @Yura Ivanov, в противовес предложу [j.u.File.delete()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/File.html#delete%28%29). Объект продолжает описывать некий путь, только еще не созданный.

Comment: @Yura Ivanov, в PHP unlink все-таки слишком рано появился, чтобы могла быть альтернатива.

Comment: @Nofate, все верно, если *работаем* с файлом, значит можем его создать, изменить, удалить и т.д. а если только удалить надо, зачем объект создавать? к тому же методы эти разные по функционалу... И в качестве ответа на вопрос можно заметить, что есть и тот и другой вариант.

Comment: @Yura Ivanov, так я и не опровергаю вашу точку зрения. Я больше с целью дополнить пример предложил.

Answer (score 1):

Объект `java.nio.file.Path` - это сущность *пути*. **Если есть объект `Path`, то это вовсе не значит, что на диске есть файл или папка**.  По такому пути файл может существовать, а может и не существовать. Путь - просто строка определённого вида.

С путём можно производить действия: проверить, является ли он абсолютным, обрезать его, проверить, с чего он начинается и так далее. Если бы мы писали `path.delete()`, то это бы звучало как "удалить путь". Путь - вещь абстрактная, его нельзя удалить. Можно удалить только файл, который находиться по этому пути. И поэтому классе `Path` вообще содержаться методы для работы лишь с абстрактным путём, а не с реальными файлами.

А вот в утилитном классе `java.nio.file.Files` содержаться методы для работы с *реальными файлами*. Для получения *размера файла, который находится по этому пути*, *для удаления файла, который находится по этому пути*. В этом классе **только статические методы**, так как привязывать объект к какому-либо файлу некорректно, см. комментарий `@Yura Ivanov`. А то будет вот как: вы создаёте объект-файл, вызываете на него метод `delete()`... И что? Файла нет... Тогда объект превращается уже не в файл, а в путь (вот класс, описывающий путь у нас и есть).

А если вам кажется неудобной запись `Files.delete(path)`, то вы можете использовать более старый класс для работы с файлами - `java.io.File`. При его использовании как раз и пишут `file.delete()`. Но имейте ввиду, что метод `delete()`, как и многие другие методы класса `java.io.File`, в случае ошибки возвращает `false`, а не кидает исключение. Да и методов в классе `File` меньше, чем в `Files` и `Path`, и вообще у класса `File` недостатков хватает, вот в `java7` и создали класс `Files` и интерфейс `Path`.